# Calling javaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I am adding my external .js file as

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="service/js/test.js"></script>
</head>
```

Inside the `test.js` I have one function called `functionTest()`.

Calling this function onload of the body is working fine;

```
<body onload="functionTest()">

</body>
```

My Question is:

I want to call this function two time in the two different divs. How should I achieve this ?

```
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <!-- Directly Want to call functionTest() when div is getting loaded -->
    </div>
   <div id="right">
       <!-- Directly Want to call functionTest() when div is getting loaded -->
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by div loaded.... who is loading the div

Comment: What do you want to achieve by calling a function after each div is loaded? Why don't you call the function when the document is loaded? may be use jQuery ready (https://api.jquery.com/ready/) ?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican : I have predefine widgets in the javaScript file. Each widget have some different UI and functioning. I just want to embed the widgets in the HTML file for Demonstration.

Comment: You could do something like, $( document ).ready( function(){ functionTest($('#left'));  functionTest($('#right')); } ), then you get function called for both widgets while not having to write js inside your html

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican : Thanks for response. I will try that also. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the call to the function at the end of the `div`. The function `functionTest` will be called when the `div` is completely loaded.

```
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <!-- Directly Want to call functionTest() when div is getting loaded -->

        <script>functionTest();</script>
        <!--    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <!-- Directly Want to call functionTest() when div is getting loaded -->

        <script>functionTest();</script>
        <!--    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just insert `<script> functionTest() </script>` inside each div