# Call Javascript function when HTML table finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am loading an HTML table through Django:

```
{% for  m in pays %}
                <tr>
                    <td><center>{{ m.bid }}</center></td>
                    <td><center>{{ m.pDate }}</center></td>
                    <td><center>{{ m.punt }}</center></td>

                </tr>
```

After this table has the necessary rows filled up. I want to call a function that makes this a datatable.

```
function inittable(){
         $('#pt').DataTable();
}
```

Right now, I am initalizing it when the form submits. This causes it to try and load on an empty table. I only want to initalize after table loads

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31019251/2025923 will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whether put the script after the table

```
{% for  m in pays %}
                <tr>
                    <td><center>{{ m.bid }}</center></td>
                    <td><center>{{ m.pDate }}</center></td>
                    <td><center>{{ m.punt }}</center></td>

                </tr>
{% endfor %}

<script>
function inittable(){
         $('#pt').DataTable();
}
</script>
```

or put it anywhere in your page inside `$( document ).ready()`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#pt').DataTable();
    });
```